# Find out last modified file date

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using visual studio 2008 and .net framework 3.5.

I am uploading file  using asp.net fileupload control.
I am using file from my local drive from the location "E:/ABC.xls" for uploading to server using my .net website.

Let's consider that file "ABC.xls" is last modified  on 1-Aug-2015 and I am uploading to server on the 21-oct-2015.

My query is how can get file's last modified date (which is 1-Aug-2015) of the file uploaded to server?

I want to show  user,last modified date from local computer  at the time of uploading file to server

Thanks ,
Prashant Kamble

Comment: show what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime dateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I just thought that in this instance, the class name "File" and the method "GetLastWriteTime" made it obvious enough. But I will improve my answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using System.IO.GetLastWriteTime should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do this 
`FileInfo` class provides access to the file literally

Firstly :

You can use `FileInfo`

```
 if (File.Exists("FileName")
 {
     FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(args[0]);
     touchFile(fi);
 }

static void touchFile(FileSystemInfo fsi)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Touching: {0}", fsi.FullName);

            // Update the CreationTime, LastWriteTime and LastAccessTime.
            try
            {
                // Set or Get Creation ,LastWriteTime ,LastAccessTime

                fsi.CreationTime = fsi.LastWriteTime = fsi.LastAccessTime =
                    DateTime.Now;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Secondly :

```
File.GetLastWriteTime  File.GetLastWriteTimeUTC
```

Referance [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)